# Iterating through content controls selected via tags and replace their text with a single value

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, word-contentcontrol

I am very new to VBA and I am using it in MS Word 2016. I have an ActiveX text box (conFull) for a full name and I am wanting to pull out the first name and populate it throughout the document. I got this to work once, and then Word froze up on me with every subsequent attempt. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub conFull_LostFocus()
    For Each ContentControl In ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("nameTag")
        With ContentControl
            .Range.Text = Split(conFull.Text, " ")(0)
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm on a mobile device so can't test, BUT try using a variable name that is NOT a reserved keyword for the iteration. VBA is *not* case-sensitive so it doesn't matter how `ContentControl` is capitalized, it's still the way the Word object model uses it. Try, for example, `cc` or `theContentControl` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Why not use separate content controls for the given name & surname, and have the given-name content control mapped with all the others you want the value replicated in? No code required. See: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html, https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html

Comment: macropod - Thank you! You are a lifesaver. I do not have enough reputation to accept your answer or vote it up, or I would. :(